# How to use new android.support.v8 in eclipse

Tags: android

wonder if someone have faced with this issue:
i'm using android eclipse. 
i'm trying to use android.support.v4, android.support.v7 and android.support.v8. but, it seems not to support all of them, together.

My question is that how can i handle my code each time there is new android.support.
thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you use Gradle or Maven (or sth else?) to configure your project environment?

Comment: Eclipse is already deprecated. Change to Android Studio. Eclipse use only for making tutorials ;-)